# Set TTL for documents in Couchbase Server

Tags: couchbase

I want to set TTL (time to live) at couchbase server for all documents getting pushed from mobile devices continuously for replication. I did not find any clear explanation/example in documentation to do this.
What should be the approach to set TTL for documents coming from mobile devices to Server through Sync Gateway.

Approach 1:
One approach is to create a view at server side which would return createdDate as key. We will query that view for keys of today date which would return today documents and we can set TTL for those documents. But how and when would we call this view and is it a good approach?

Approach 2:
Should I do it by using webhooks where it will listen to document changes (creations) made through Couchbase Lite push replications, set TTL for new documents and save back to Couchbase server?

Is there any other better way to do it?

Also what is the way to set TTL for only specific documents?

EDIT: My final approach:
I will create following view at couchbase server:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(dateToArray(doc.createdDate));
}
```

I will have a job which would run daily at EOD, query view to get documents created today and set TTL for those documents.
In this way I would be able to delete documents regularly.

Let me know if there is any issue with it or there is any better way.

Comment: Which library are you using for accessing `Couchbase`? Every library provides methods like `add` and `set` in which there is surely a parameter via which you can set the TTL for the Key. For setting TTL for only specific documents refer http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdks/dotnet-2.2/time-to-live.html

Comment: I am using .net sdk. I have gone through above document. But where will it fit in the flow where documents get replicated from mobile devices to Server through Sync Gateway? How will I access those documents and set TTL for same?

Comment: The place where in your system you have access to Couchbase via library, there you will use the library function to set the TTL. Every document will be identified by a key. So you need to pass on this key information to library. Suppose, Module_A has access to Couchbase and reuest to replicate documents is generated in Module_X, then you need to pass out all the necessary information from Module_X to Module_A. Also Module_X should have information of document and the `Key` which represents the document in Couchbase.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone from the mobile team can chime in and confirm this, but I don't think that the mobile SDK allows to set an expiry at the moment.

I guess you could add the creation/update time to your document and create a batch job that uses the "core" SDKs to periodically find old documents (either via N1QL or a dedicated view) and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to set a TTL for documents via Sync Gateway like you can with a Couchbase Server smart-client. There is a conceptual impedance mismatch with Sync Gateway using the native-style TTLs on documents. This is because the Sync Gateway protocol functions on the basis of [revision trees](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/revision/index.html) and even when a document is 'deleted', there is still a document in place to mark that there is a document that has been deleted.

I would also be wary of workloads which might require TTLs (e.g. a cache), Sync Gateway documents take up space even after they've been deleted so your dataset may continue to grow unbounded.

If you do require TTLs, and if you do not think the dataset size will be an issue then the best way would be to store a field in the document that represents the time the document would expire. Then you would do two things:

- When accessing the document, if it has expired then you manually delete it
- Periodically iterate over the [all docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/database/get-all-docs/index.html) endpoint and delete any documents you find with an expiry time in the past.

Comment: I am going with approach mentioned in the end of my question. Please do let me know if there is any issue with it.

Comment: I would be extremely wary of setting a TTL on any document created by Sync Gateway as Sync Gateway will not expect the document to be removed without it being communicated through the Sync Gateway directly.

Comment: I have found a workaround to communicate deletion of document at server to sync gateway. I will have a shadow bucket configured for sync bucket. Deletion will happen on shadow bucket and this change will be replicated to sync bucket through sync gateway which would set necessary metadata for that document (e.g. _deleted = true). Now this deletion change will get replicated to mobile devices automatically. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: That *should* work, I would be extremely careful with using shadow buckets as they're due to be formally deprecated (And they're not even officially documented). You will also need to be careful with the behaviour of the shadow bucket in relation to revision trees as deleting the document in the shadow bucket might leave other active revisions in the sync gateway bucket.

Comment: Any idea what kind of logic would replace _Shadowing_ when it deprecates? Will we be able to use that logic in our case?

Comment: There are long-term plans to create stronger integration between Sync Gateway and Couchbase server that would allow you to use a single bucket and would make Couchbase SDKs 'mobile-aware' you can see more information here: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-17228 . What exact shape this would take is not yet known.

Answer (score -1):

Couchbase does not delete when TTL reached;
Instead, when you access (expired) document,
then Couchbase check expiry, remove it at that moment.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/developer-guide/expiry.html

Comment: Ok but my question is what should be the approach to set TTL for documents coming from mobile devices to Server through Sync Gateway.

Comment: This briefly confused me a lot; this answer is incorrect. The documents aren't deleted immediately when they expire, or immediately after being accessed after expiration; they're deleted when a periodic process (the expiry pager) scans for and removes expired documents. A clearer explanation is here https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/understanding-couchbase/buckets-memory-and-storage/expiration.html#bucket_ttl_use_cases